# Issues getting an image to become a submit button

Tags: javascript, image, css, background-image

I am trying to make my submit button turn into an arrow, but with a background. Like this:

[image]

I was able to get the submit button to appear in the input, however, it isn't taking up the full height of it for some reason. I uploaded an image to my server of an arrow like the one in the example, but whenever I un-comment out the background-image and no-repeat, it doesn't do anything with the background image. I am unsure if I am going about this right. I looked at other questions on here, I just can't this to work.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

```css
#footer-grid1-newsletter-input {
 margin-top: 15px;
 width: 80%;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 8px 5px;
}
#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit {
 /*background:url(http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/right-arrow.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
 height: 39px;
 margin-left: -54px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 0;
 background: #0085A1;
 color: #FFF:
    -webkit-appearance: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit:hover {
 background: rgb(69,186,149);
}
```

```html
    <input type="email" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-input" placeholder="Your Email Address">
 <input type="submit" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit" name="submit">
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it doesn't do anything with the background image. _ ?

Comment: The answer you just gave is almost exactly what I was looking for except if there is a way to keep the arrow over the submit button on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `background-color`(specific property of `background`) property over `:hover` as if we use **`background`**, it will override all `background` properties

Try this:

```css
#footer-grid1-newsletter-input {
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 8px 5px;
}
#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit {
  background: url('http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/right-arrow.png') #0085A1 center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 39px;
  margin-left: -54px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#footer-grid1-newsletter-submit:hover {
  background-color: rgb(69, 186, 149)
}
```

```html
<input type="email" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-input" placeholder="Your Email Address">
<input type="submit" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit" name="submit" value='&nbsp'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a background image try an image input.

```
<input type="image" id="footer-grid1-newsletter-submit"  src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/icons/right-arrow.png" name="submit">
```

**EDIT**

Try this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j031/ydc68y0a/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<input type="submit">`, use `<button type="submit"></button>` and put your image inside the button. Alternatively, use a Unicode arrow as in this example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.value = 'Form Submitted!';
  }
}
```

```css
div.input {
  border: none;
  width: 20rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

input {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 2rem;
  width: 18rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #0074D9;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

label::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

#result {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div class="input">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email Address..." required>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">&#10142;</button>
  </div>
  <label for="result">Result:</label>
  <textarea id="result"></textarea></result>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set opacity property of submit button to 0 to be completely transparent.